# Beamer: uncover a formula from inner to outer

Tags: beamer

With the following code

```
\documentclass[beamer]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \[
    \sqrt{\uncover<2->{a\uncover<3->{+b}}}
  \]
\end{frame}    
\end{document}
```

I can uncover a formula showing first outer elements then the inner ones.

How can I obtain the converse? That is: first display the "+b", then the "a" in front of it, then the square root sign around the sum?

Comment: A professor of mine did this on the blackboard. This provides a very handy way to explain a rather complicated formula on a step-by-step basis.

Answer (score 12):

The square root is the problem.

```
\documentclass[beamer]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
  \only<1>{\phantom{\sqrt{\vphantom{a+b}}}\hphantom{a}+b}
  \only<2>{\phantom{\sqrt{\vphantom{a+b}}}a+b}
  \only<3>{\sqrt{a+b}}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, this works, thanks. But do you think this is the only way? I mean: the example is small, of course, but with big formulas it can be a pain to extend it...

Comment: @brad I understand, but the square root must know what it applies to.

Comment: Do you mean that if something is covered in the current slide then it is not even computed? If so, I agree that there is no other solution. In that case, maybe a workaround for a complicated formula could be to use white ink for the whole formula and black from the inner to the outer...

Comment: For this particular case, it might be easier to use power notation, as in `x=(\uncover<1->a\uncover<2->{+b})\uncover<3->{^{1/2}}`.

Comment: @brad You can avoid most of the work using a good editor. You can just write the first equation, then copy & paste the line remove an `\*phantom` command, copy and paste the line etc. For example in vim it wouldn't take many keystrokes: `Yp` to do the copy pasting of the whole line, `dawxhx` to remove the `\*phantom{` and `wx` to remove the right `}`, `T<rn` to change the number to `n` (with minor tweaks depending on the line). You can produce that kind of output at about 15 keystrokes per line.

Comment: @Bakuriu I do use vim and I am aware of its features: the point is that I was looking for a way to obtain the effect from beamer itself, not as a hack. In my naivety, I thought that something like `\uncover<3->{\sqrt{\uncover<2->{a\uncover<1->{+b}}}}` should do the job, but it doesn't.

Comment: @egreg I can't fully understand the difference bewteen `\phantom,\vphantom,\hphantom`. I see that using just `\phantom` doesn't work neatly, but I can't understand why.

Comment: @egreg Ok, I found the meaning of `\phantom,\vphantom,\hphantom` and I understood your example.

Answer (score 4):

I worked a little bit more on my example (I need it for a somewhat more complicated formula) and I discovered that inner `\textcolor` have priority on outer ones, so the following works:

```
\begin{frame}
  \[
    \textcolor<3>{black}{\textcolor<1-2>{white}{%
      \sqrt{%
        \textcolor<2>{black}{\textcolor<1>{white}{%
          a%
          \textcolor<1>{black}{%
            \vphantom{a}+b%
          }%
        }}%
      }%
    }}%
  \]
\end{frame}
```

In my case, I can generalize this easier than @egreg suggestion (which is, anyway, very nice and "TeXnical")
As a more elaborated example, consider the following:

```
\begin{frame}
  \[
    \textcolor<6>{black}{\textcolor<1-5>{white}{%
    \textcolor<5->{black}{\textcolor<4>{red}{%
      {\sqrt{%
    \textcolor<3->{black}{\textcolor<2>{red}{%
        {\left(%
    \textcolor<2->{black}{\textcolor<1>{red}{%
          {\frac{a}{2}}%
      }}%
          \right)^{2}}%
      }}%
    \textcolor<4->{black}{\textcolor<3>{red}{%
      {\vphantom{1}+b}%
      }}%
      }}%
      }}%
    \textcolor<6->{black}{\textcolor<5>{red}{%
        {\vphantom{1}+\frac{c}{2}}%
      }}%
      }}%
  \]
\end{frame}
```